# When we pass string variable as ref argument to function and change value of string variable in function

Tags: c#, string, immutability

```
static void Main()
{
   String str="sample";
   ChangeString(ref str);
}
void ChangeString(ref string str)
{ 
   str="New Sample";
}
```

In terms of memory it will create new instance or update the existing instance while we passed ref  pointer to the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking about 2 separate things:

**1. Strings and String Data**

There are 2 parts to a `String` variable:

1. the string variable itself, and
2. the string data

In your example, `str` is a variable and "sample" and "New Sample" are each string datas.

At first, variable `str` points to string data "sample". Inside your `ChangeString` function, you are assigning a new string data "New Sample" to the `str` variable. The string data "sample" is not being changed.

In fact, look at this example:

```
static void Main()
{
   String str1 = "sample";
   String str2 = str1;
   ChangeString(ref str1);
}
void ChangeString(ref string str)
{ 
   str = "New Sample";
}
```

Here, `str1` will change to point to new string data "New Sample", but `str2` will continue to point to the original "Sample" data.

**2. Keyword `ref`**

Normally, when a parameter is passed to a function, the variable is copied from the original input to the parameter variable of the function. So in example above, if the `ref` keyword was not used, then the variable `str1` would have been copied to the `str` variable. Note that I say the variable, and not the variable data. Both `str1` and `str` would point to the same string data, just like `str1` and `str2` did.

Once inside the function, acting on the varable `str` would then have no effect on the `str1` variable.

However, since you are using the `ref` keyword, that copy is not happening. Instead, the variable `str` becomes like an alias for `str1`. So when `str` is modified, so is `str1`.

This is functionally equivalent to the following:

```
static void Main()
{
   String str1 = "sample";
   String str2 = str1;
   str1 = "New Sample";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Passing a reference type as a parameter doesn't create a new instance, neither with or without the `ref` keyword. The code inside the `ChangeString` method will assign a new instance to the variable.

Strings in .NET are immutable, so you can't change them. When a string is assigned to a string variable, the reference in the variable is replaced by the reference to the new string.

---

Note though that both the strings objects for the literal strings `"sample"` and `"New Sample"` are created when the application starts. The code doesn't create any new string instances when the assignment happens, it only gets a reference to a string object that was created earlier.